# How to create one GWT WebApp, but with more than one WAR files

Tags: gwt

I am working on an enterprise application using GWT as the front end. I have multiple modules and would like to create each individual module as separate war file, when deployed in the same web server would perform like a single webapp so that the user dont need to change the URL to access each module.

Hope the question is clear, can any one please guide me with this.

Comment: could you give more detail of your architecture: which servlet container you use, the name of the modules and which paths would you rewrite, how do client-side consume services, if you use a web-server like apache as front-end between the user and the servlet container, etc

Answer (score 2):

I've created demo project on Github where described working approach for development plugin-oriented systems: https://github.com/domax/gwt-dynamic-plugins

Please feel free to ask me more about this approach - your interest will stimulate me to continue working on it ;].

Comment: I am really looking for such a solution for my application, I have searched the internet and was not able to find any good tutorial for the same. Can you please give a detailed information about your approach so that i can use the same in my project.

Comment: @user2176322: It is really not simple. I created and polished this approach several months. I plan to create some kind of tutorial or step-by-step instruction how to build such projects. My first intention was to create a project on Github, but i'd glad to hear other ideas how to present it.
Any other help will be also appreciated.

Comment: Hi Domax,have you created some kind of tutorial for the same, if so can you please share that. Or can you give me ur email id where i can contact you directly.I have run it to such a scenario where i cannot proceed with out splitting the war file.

Comment: I started to prepare the simple sample. It even works already, but it is still in progress. Feel free to clone and add issues.
https://github.com/domax/gwt-dynamic-plugins

Answer (score 1):

**The simplest solution would be to compile multiple modules as separate gwt applications and then package them in the same war.**

In your deployment war you will end up with multiapp.war

The layout fo the war would be -

```
webapps
    -> multiapp
     --> module1gwtapp/
     --> module2gwtapp/
     --> module3gwtapp/
     --> styles/images
     --> styles/css
     --> WEB-INF/web.xml
     --> WEB-INF/lib
     --> WEB-INF/classes
```

### PROs

1. This approach avoids duplicated dependency jars by sharing the
   WEB-INF/lib jars across multiple gwt apps.
2. This approach avoids duplicated css/images by sharing them across multiple gwt apps.
3. Session management would be same for the multiple apps.

### Cons

1. Navigation between apps would mean reload of apps.
2. History management would be a bit tricky.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I worked with GWT, it is not possible (I may be wrong). One webApp can have only one war file.

You can however merge number of modules so that it can be included in single module. You can have even multiple entrypoints for the same package but there can be only one war per application.

If you want multiple `.war` files, segregate you project into multiple projects and build them individually and hope that it will not break.

Answer (score 0):

You have different possibilities depending on your apps.

If each of your apps needs its own server-side services, you have to deploy each .war independently, then you can use a web-server like apache as a front-end which links all applications using rewrite and http-proxy rules, in this case you can have your apps in different servers and even configure cluster and balancing.

If your apps are just client stuff, you could unpack all the wars (use jar or unzip commands) and put all the static files anywhere: in a web server or even in a unique .war.

You could as well join all your modules in a final .war using maven. The basic procedure should be to create a new module to join all other modules using the unpack-dependencies goal of the maven-dependency-plugin, then you could compile all gwt modules configuring appropriately the gwt-maven plugin.